# Run npm postscript after Ctrl+C the server

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running my development DB inside a container.

I intend to automate starting and stoping the container with `npm`, thus I added some `pre` and `post` scripts to my `package.json`:

```
"prewatch": "docker start mongo",
"watch": "nodemon app.js",
"postwatch": "docker stop mongo"
```

The problem I find is that my `post` script won't run after shutting down `nodemon` with `Ctrl+C`.

Any ideas to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Did will adding in [nodemon config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#config-files) on [events](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/wiki/Events#states) script could solve your problem?

For example, via package.json:

```
{

  "nodemonConfig": {
    "events": {
      "crash": "docker stop mongo"
    } 
  }
}
```

Update:

TLDR: nodemon events does not work here, disabling `restartable` allow to achieve expected behavior.

With adding to config `restartable: false` like that:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "echo \"npm:prestart\"",
    "start": "nodemon server.js", 
    "poststart": "echo \"npm:poststart\""
  },

  "nodemonConfig": {
    "restartable": false,
    "events": {
      "start": "echo \"Start event\"",
      "crash": "echo \"Crash event\"",
      "exit": "echo \"Exit event\""
    }
  },
```

And start it with `npm start -- -V` and press `Ctrl+c` **twice** I got the following:

```sh
> nodemon_events@1.0.0 prestart /home/kyr/test/nodemon_events
> echo "npm:prestart"

npm:prestart

> nodemon_events@1.0.0 start /home/kyr/test/nodemon_events
> nodemon server.js "-V"

[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] reading config ./package.json
[nodemon] send SIGHUP to 8929 to restart
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] bind start -> `echo "Start event"`
[nodemon] bind crash -> `echo "Crash event"`
[nodemon] bind exit -> `echo "Exit event"`
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 8942
Start event
[nodemon] watching 2 files
server:run
[nodemon] exiting

> nodemon_events@1.0.0 poststart /home/kyr/test/nodemon_events
> echo "npm:poststart"

npm:poststart
```

It looks a lottle strange, but may solve your problem.